# Fixed bottom in sidebar

Tags: html, css, footer

im working right now on a custom admin template and i have a lil problem here. i have the two list points called `.logout` at the bottom of the left sidebar. the problem is that if i zoom into it they will move up and lays over the other menu points but i whant them at the bottom of it

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

thats the **css** that the sidebar footer has.

```
.offcanvas-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

and thats the style of the offcanva sidebar
 if i gave the footer a `position relative` it will dock under the calender post and not at the bottom anymore. by `position:absolute` i will have the same problems again

[demo](http://kallax.awesom-media.de/)

Comment: Please don't link to an external site where the code is under active development... I just tried to debug your issues and witnessed your code changing live. Reduce your issue to a minimum, viable, reproducible example using Stack Overflow or JSFiddle.

Comment: sorry, i changed it back to the original. my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.sidebar-menu.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: this one works with the bottom. but if i zoom into the site the two bottom icons will move up and lay over the other one.

Comment: Then you need to set a media-query for that resolution that applies a position relative to that div when the screen arrives to that resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Try below css in your code

```
#menu{
overflow:auto;
}
```

no need of below css

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0px;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the last two list points are not at the bottom. i would like to have them at the end of the sidebar. i updated the file and as you see it is still under the point "Kalender"